# JPL Prolog/JAVA connection

Tags: eclipse, prolog, ffi, jpl

I want to consult my Prolog project from the eclipse console. 
I Installed: SWI PROLOG 32 bit and ECLIPSE LUNA 32 bit
About environment system variable...
I added `SWI_HOME_DIR` with my path of swi prolog, that is `C:\Program Files(x86)\swipl;`

I added to `path` variable at the end  ;`%PrologPath%\bin;%PrologPath%\lib\jpl.jar ;`

What should I do to get the output of the prolog-project to my console ? What kind of project should i build in eclipse, and what kind of java file should I create ? 
Can someone give me some code to consult my prolog-project ? My prolog-project is in the prolog home `( C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\project1\src\file.pl )`

Comment: Do you just want to run a prolog program *from eclipse*? Or are you trying to use java types in a prolog program (using http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/prolog_api/overview.html)?

Comment: The first ! I want to consult, ask queries to .pl file, directly from eclipse, avoiding the query method, for example :   
Query q = new Query(inputstr);
System.out.println("first solution of " + q + ": X = " + q.oneSolution().get("X"));
I want the prolog "flow" directly on my eclipse's console .